# OrderBy in Angular/html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have this code:

```
<div flex="66">
            <h3>{{ hack.title }}</h3>
            <h4>{{ hack.description }}</h4>
            <h4>{{ hack.status }}</h4>
            <p>Backs: {{ hacksCtrl.getBacks(hack.id) }}</p>
          </div>
```

I basically want to order by `Backs` basically meaning `likes`, so the more likes something has the higher up the page it will appear.

So i did this but it is not working:

```
ng-repeat="hack in hacksCtrl.hacks | orderBy: hacksCtrl.getBacks()"
```

any ideas?

thanks

controller below:

```
 import Chance from 'chance';
export default function(hack, $state, $sce, HacksService, user) {
  const vm = this;
  vm.hack = hack;

  vm.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  };

  vm.save = function() {
    HacksService.save(vm.hack);
    $state.go('hacks.view', {
      id: vm.hack.id
    });
  };

  vm.create = function() {
    const chance = new Chance();

    vm.hack.id = chance.guid();
    vm.hack.status = 'proposed';
    vm.hack.createdBy = user.name;
    vm.hack.userProfileImage = user.picture;
    HacksService.create(vm.hack);
    $state.go('hacks.view', {
      id: vm.hack.id
    });
  };

  vm.like = function(id, $event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    HacksService.like(id, user);
  };
  vm.hasLiked = function() {
    const userId = user.id;
    const likes = vm.hack.likes;

    if (likes) {
      return (likes.indexOf(userId) !== -1);
    }
  };
  vm.getLikes = function() {
    return (vm.hack.likes) ? vm.hack.likes.length : 0;
  };

  vm.isCreate = function() {
    return !vm.hack;
  };

  vm.goToEdit = function(id) {
    $state.go('hacks.edit', {
      id: id
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: put a variable in your scope that has hacksCtrl.getBacks(hack.id) and try order by with the scope variable

Comment: by why does `orderBy: hack.title` not order it alphabetically?

Comment: please show the controller script

Comment: the problem here is very basic, you try to order by `likes` of a single id `orderBy: hacksCtrl.getBacks(hack.id)` which is wrong, preferably you should extend the `hack` object with property `backs/likes` and assign correct value there

Comment: added controller @GuenterGuckelsberger

Answer (score 1):

Your getBacks function is missing the id param.

edit: Inspect the getBacks function and check if the values it returns are the ones you expected. I'm not sure from your code if you fetch that data separately.

Answer (score 1):

For your function, pass in the entire hack object and then just name the function in the orderBy statement

```
vm.getBacks = function(hack) {
    return (hack.backers) ? hack.backers.length : 0;
};
```

Your angular repeat would look something like this:

```
ng-repeat="hack in hacksCtrl.hacks | orderBy: hacksCtrl.getBacks"
```

Comment: tried this and does not seem to work, code has been changed by someone else so i'll repost what i have now

Comment: I do not see a "getBacks" function in your controller anymore. Am I missing it?

Comment: it got changed to getLikes

Comment: I have simplified the code and placed it in this jsfiddle. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/birwin0000/ujxa3wmh/4/

Comment: if birwin's solution doesn't work for you then you should check if you have the likes data at the time the filter's being called (eg. you're fetching it separately from server and since everything works asynchronously the filter gets called before you get the response)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because, [as stated in the Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), orderBy expects its argument to be one of:

> - `function`: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the `<`, `===`, `>` operator.
> - `string`: An Angular expression. The result of this expression is used to compare elements (for example name to sort by a property called name or name.substr(0, 3) to sort by 3 first characters of a property called name). The result of a constant expression is interpreted as a property name to be used in comparisons (for example "special name" to sort object by the value of their special name property). An expression can be optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name). If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.
> - `Array`: An array of function or string predicates. The first predicate in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent, the next predicate is used.

`hackCtrls.getBack(hack.id)` is none of the above.

Thus, to fix your problem, you could pass the callback to orderBy instead or bind a "like" property onto the hacks and sort by property name:

1. `ng-repeat="hack in hacksCtrl.hacks | orderBy: hacksCtrl.getBacks"`, and modify getBacks would be:

   ```
   vm.getBacks = function(hack) {
      return hack.backers ? hack.backers.length : 0;
   }
   ```

   It is necessary that `vm.hacks = [/* multiple hacks */]`
2. `ng-repeat="hack in hacksCtrl.hacks | orderBy: 'likes'`, assuming hacks have the `like` property.

Comment: ok makes sense and i tried both of your solutions but neither seemed to work?

Comment: Because getbacks has to take an argument (the hack), now getBacks just look at one hack? Don't you have a array of them? Why are they not defined in the controller?

Comment: it is not my code so im not too sure. so what should i set to what in order to make it an array and therefore be able to sort it?